# How to open a v-list-group by default?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

How to open a `v-list-group` by default?

I tried `value` as it says in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-group/#props-value):

[image: value documentation]

So this is my simplified Vuetify 3 (3.3.14) code using `value` to expand the `v-list-group` by default:

```html
<v-list>
  <v-list-group :value="isOpen1">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <v-list-item/>
    </template>
    <v-list-item/>
  </v-list-group>
  <v-list-group :value="isOpen2">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <v-list-item/>
    </template>
    <v-list-item/>
  </v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

...

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen1: true,
      isOpen2: true
    }
  }
}
```

But now it is closed by default and when I open (expand) either of the two `v-list-group` items, both are opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `value` prop on the v-list-group sets an identifier for the group. Using the [`opened`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list/#props-opened) prop on the surrounding list, you can pass in an array with group identifiers to indicate which groups are opened:

```html
<v-list v-model:opened="openedGroups">
  <v-list-group value="group1">
    ...
  </v-list-group>
  <v-list-group value="group2">
    ...
  </v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

and

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      openedGroups: ['group1']
    }
  }
}
```

Have a look at the [example from the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#sub-group)

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly!

I just added `open-strategy="multiple"` to the v-list.